# FFImageLoading Load image from Mobile-Sdcard

Tags: android, xamarin, ffimageloading

I'm trying to load image from mobile.
Same method with picasso is working fine but i get problem using FFImageloading

```
var CatalogCategories = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).ToString(), "dbsoft");
ImageService.Instance.LoadFile(new Java.IO.File(CatalogCategories, "Main.jpg")).Into(MainImage);
```

I getting Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Java.IO.File' to 'string'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LoadFile` method's parameter should be `string`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructs a new TaskParameter to load an image from a file.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The new TaskParameter.</returns>
/// <param name="filepath">Path to the file.</param>
TaskParameter LoadFile(string filepath);
```

You need use File's [AbsolutePath](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Java.IO.File.AbsolutePath/) property to get the string path:

```
ImageService.Instance.LoadFile(new Java.IO.File(CatalogCategories, "Main.jpg").AbsolutePath).Into(MainImage);
```

### Update

The `Into` method's parameter should be `ImageViewAsync`, so you should use `ImageViewAsync` in your layout:

```
<FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
    android:id="@+id/mainImage"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your .cs file:

```
ImageViewAsync MainImage = FindViewById<ImageViewAsync>(Resource.Id.mainImage);
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Android.Widget.ImageView' to 'FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync'